# How to center image when creating images from PDF using GhostScript

Tags: pdf, centering, ghostscript

I have several pdf files with different sizes and different width to height ratios. Now I want to create fixed-size thumbnails from 1st page of these files.
I do this using this command:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=d:\test\a.jpeg -dJPEGQ=100 -g509x750 -dUseCropBox=true  -dPDFFitPage=true -q  d:\test\a.pdf -c quit
```

Since the original files are of different widths and heights but thumbnails should be of the same size, there will be white margins in the **right side** or **top** of the thumbnails. But I want to have **equal margins** on top and bottom (or right and left) of the thumbnail (just like thumbnail displayed in windows explorer).

Is there any way to do it using GhostScript?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, but not with a single switch, and not while using -dPDFFitPage.

PDFFitPage will scale the content isomorphicallly (ie the same in each direction), so you will **either** have white margins at the top **or** the right of the output.

In order to centre the content, you need to duplicate the functionality of PDFFitPage, and also translate the origin in either the x or y direction, by half the 'excess' in whichever direction has space left over.

You can find the code which performs the scaling in /ghostpdl/gs/Resource/Init/pdf_main.ps, look for /pdf_PDF2PS_matrix and then:

```
  //systemdict /PDFFitPage known {
    PDFDEBUG { (Fiting PDF to imageable area of the page.) = flush } if
    currentpagedevice /.HWMargins get aload pop
    currentpagedevice /PageSize get aload pop
    % Adjust PageSize and .HWMargins for the page portrait/landscape orientation
```

Note that as far as I can see, the current implementation already does centre the output:

```
% stack: savedCTM <pdfpagedict> [Box] scale XImageable YImageable XBox YBox
3 index 2 index 6 index mul sub 2 div 3 index 2 index 7 index mul sub 2 div
PDFDEBUG { (    Centering translate by [ ) print 1 index =print (, ) print dup =print ( ]) = flush } if
translate pop pop pop pop
```

Comment: What a pitty! I was using version 8.7.1. This problem is fixed in current version(9.15), Thank you